# Compose compiler upgrade

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This version (1.3.2) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.7.20 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.9.0 which is not known to be compatible.

The Kotlin version and Compose compilation version do not match, so I want to upgrade the compilation version, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of compose compiler plugin is defined in the `build.gradle` file of your app/module, see [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler#declaring_dependencies):

```
android {
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.3.2"
    }
}
```

You can find the compose to kotlin compatibility map [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin#pre-release_kotlin_compatibility).